# How to unwind to home, and then segue forward in one action

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, segue, unwind-segue

I want to tap the "Go To DestinationVC" button in the SourceVC, and have it safely unwind back home, and then segue forward via a different route to the DestinationVC.

I tried just calling a performSegue in side the unwinding segue function:

```
@IBAction func UnwindAndSegueToDestination(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegToDest", sender: nil)
}
```

However, this results in the DestinationVC briefly loading, and then being replace with the HomeVC.

[image: Storyboard Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend putting it in the viewDidAppear of the HomeVC if doing it the way you described isn't working. I would pass a Bool value during the unwind segue that tells the Home VC to triggers a segue in the viewDidAppear. Once that segue is triggered, make sure to set that Bool value to false again. Obviously the Bool value would be passed in the prepare to segue method in the source VC.

Comment: I can add more details or code if necessary. Just let me know what code you want me to add.

Comment: I actually had that thought too. However, it seems there would be a more direct method available.

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to have the animations that show the user moving between pages, this would probably be your best bet. If you don't want the animations then you can instantiate a new VC and clear all the VCs below.

Comment: I went ahead and did it this way. It works well. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing any other methods still, if anyone knows a better way.